# HUE UI doesn't show progress when running some pig script, and the task can't be stopped

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera, hue

It's weird that for some pig script, the HUE UI doesn't show "progress" when running it. It only shows "No available logs." No progress bar (yellow, green, or red). Sorry I'm new I can't post screenshots.

The script is as simple as just loading a table, nothing else.

Moreover, the script can't be stopped. After the stop square is hit, the screen just stays unchanged, forever.

Very strange. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: post your script please, so that if the error is there we will be able to find it. Also post your input and expected output (or samples if they are large [in which case give an idea of total input size]) Also how long did you wait for progress to appear?

Comment: You can share screenshots or post/attached it on the Hue user list (maybe easier there for debugging questions). Which Hue version is it? Is Oozie installed?

Comment: have you tried saving the script to a file and then running from terminal? please try and post results (and error message if one appears).